# Return same YouTube video while fetch data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a bug in my apps, when I try to fetch video from YouTube. it turn into same video, since I have a a table view cell while you tap one of the item it fetch video data based on query. this is the look of my app.

[image: homeVC]

[image: videoVC]

while I tap from a different cell the video always returns the same like the pic I give, this is my code in video controller. when I try to know what happens when I tapped back with required init, it crashes say fatal error unexpected found nil when I try to print **tausiyah.name ?? ""** but if I change **tausiyah?.name ?? ""** the crash disappear.

```
var store: TausiyahStore!
var tausiyah: TausiyahItem! {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = tausiyah.name
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    store.fetchSearchVideos(matching: tausiyah.name ?? "") { (videoResult) in
        switch videoResult {
        case let .success(videos):
            print("Successfully found \(videos.count) video")
            self.videoDataSource.videos = videos
        case let .failure(error):
            print("Error fetching search video: \(error)")
            self.videoDataSource.videos.removeAll()
        }

        self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .automatic)
    }
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    print(tausiyah.name ?? "")
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

deinit {
    print(tausiyah.name ?? "")
}
```

This is my fetch image in tausiyahStore I implement in video controller

```
class TausiyahStore {
    let imageStore = ImageStore()

    func fetchSearchVideos(matching query: String, completion: @escaping (VideoResults) -> ()) {
        let parameters = ["q": query]
        let url = YoutubeAPI.youtubeURL(parameters: parameters)

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let task = sessions.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            let result = self.processVideoRequest(data: data, error: error)
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func processVideoRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> VideoResults {
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            return .failure(error!)
        }
        return YoutubeAPI.videos(fromJSON: jsonData)

    func fetchImage(for video: Video, completion: @escaping (ImagesResult) -> ()) {
        guard let videoKey = video.videoID else {
            preconditionFailure("Video expected to have a video id")
        }

        if let image = imageStore.image(forKey: videoKey) {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success(image))
            }
            return
        }

        guard let videoURL = video.url else {
            preconditionFailure("Video expected to have video url")
        }

        let request = URLRequest(url: videoURL)

        let task = sessions.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            let result = self.processImageRequest(data: data, error: error)
            print(result)

            if case let .success(image) = result {
                self.imageStore.setImage(image, forKey: videoKey)
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func processImageRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> ImagesResult {
        guard
            let imageData = data,
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                if data == nil {
                    return .failure(error!)
                } else {
                    return .failure(ThumbnailError.thumbnailCreationError)
                }
            }
        return .success(image)
    }
}
```

and this is my imageStore class to create a cache image from YoutubeAPI

```
class ImageStore {

    // Create cache image in imageStore
    let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    // MARK: Set image to store the image in the imageStore for the item's key
    func setImage(_ image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        cache.setObject(image, forKey: key as NSString)

        // To-Do: Get the URL and save the image as data
        // Create full URL for image
        let url = imageURL(forKey: key)

        // Turn image into JPEG data
        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
            // Write it to full URL
            let _ = try? data.write(to: url, options: [.atomic])
        }
    }

    // MARK: Return image data from the existing disk with key, and return it into an image
    func image(forKey key: String) -> UIImage? {

        if let existingImage = cache.object(forKey: key as NSString) {
            return existingImage
        }

        let url = imageURL(forKey: key)
        guard let imageFromDisk = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path) else { return nil }

        cache.setObject(imageFromDisk, forKey: key as NSString)

        return imageFromDisk
    }

    // MARK: Delete image from disk with key
    func deleteImage(forKey key: String) {
        cache.removeObject(forKey: key as NSString)

        let url = imageURL(forKey: key)

        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
        } catch let deleteError {
            print("Error removing the image from disk: \(deleteError)")
        }
    }

    // MARK: Store image in document directory
    private func imageURL(forKey key: String) -> URL {
        let documentsDirectories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = documentsDirectories.first!
        return documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(key)
    }
}
```

Can you show me where the bug is, appreciate your help :)

Comment: From where and how do you set the tausiyah field in your class?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan I instantiate the tausiyah in home controller, and passed in the tausiyahStore through segue

Comment: Can you log the value of tausiyah.name in viewDidLoad and make sure it has been populated before querying the video results?

Comment: yes I print the tausiyah.name and the log printing optional("Tafsir") if I select one of the item

Comment: What are you doing in fetchSearchVideos function? I can't find the function in the above code. Will there be any problem out there?

Comment: sorry I forgot, I edited the question right now

Comment: Are you sure that your YoutubeAPI.youtubeURL(parameters: parameters) works fine? Did you check that with different queries separately?

Comment: I already check it manually, but it still return the same video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201448/discussion-between-subramanian-mariappan-and-ferryawijayanto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to trouble the developer who help me in this question, I finally found the answer for my problem. The problem is lay in my YoutubeURL function in my YoutubeAPI struct, the problem is my function adding a parameters which is try to replace the existing parameters in my baseParams. I just know now that you can't replace a query that already exist, since I try to add additional query with parameters but it failed.

This is my YoutubeURL function before

```
static func youtubeURL(parameters: [String: String]?) -> URL {
        var components = URLComponents(string: baseURLString)!
        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        let baseParams = [
            "part": "snippet",
            "key": apiKey,
            "q": "tausiyah"
        ]

        for (key, value) in baseParams {
            queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
        }

        if let additionalParams = parameters {
            for (key, value) in additionalParams {
                queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
            }
        }

        components.queryItems = queryItems

        return components.url!
    }
```

This is my solution still I don't know is this the right solution, but it works though

```
static func youtubeURL(withAdditionalQuery query: String) -> URL {
        var components = URLComponents(string: baseURLString)!
        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        let baseParams = [
            "part": "snippet",
            "key": apiKey,
            "q": "tausiyah \(query)"
        ]

        for (key, value) in baseParams {
            queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
        }

        components.queryItems = queryItems
        components.percentEncodedQuery = components.percentEncodedQuery?.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: "+")

        return components.url!
    }
```

Thank you for everyone who try to help me happy coding :)